# merging two array of objects with custom compare function with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, sum

I have two array of objects like:

```
var A = [{title:"name1",count:5},{title:"name2",count:1},{title:"name3",count:3}];
```

and:

```
var B = [{title:"name2",count:7},{title:"name3",count:2},{title:"name4",count:3},{title:"name5",count:8}];
```

I need to merge this two array in one array and sum the "count" values in returned array when the "title" properties is same:
the last answer must be:

```
[{title:"name1",count:5},{title:"name2",count:8},{title:"name3",count:5},{title:"name4",count:3},{title:"name5",count:8}]
```

how can i do this???

Comment: You didn't ask a question, or show an attempt. This is like me saying "I need a Ferrari." I need to work for it ;)

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. Please read the help section and provide your attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve a result

```
var M = A.concat(B)

var C = [];

M.forEach(function(a) {
    var index;
    if (C.some(function(c, i) { index = i; return a.title == c.title; })) {
        C[index].count += a.count;
    } else {
        C.push(a);
    }
});

console.log(C); // as you expect
```

Comment: Please provide some text to provide some context for your code.

Comment: @Suever I've added some links, the rest of the code is trivial

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `Array.concat` and `Array.map` functions:

```
    var merged = A.concat(B), titles = [], result = [];

    merged.map(function(obj){
        if (titles.indexOf(obj.title) === -1) {
            titles.push(obj.title);
            result.push(obj);
        } else {
            result[titles.indexOf(obj.title)]['count'] += obj['count'];
        }
    });

    console.log(result);  // will output the expected array of objects
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this https://jsfiddle.net/menm9xeo/

```
var noMatch;

var A = [{title:"name1",count:5},{title:"name2",count:1},{title:"name3",count:3}];
var B = [{title:"name2",count:7},{title:"name3",count:2},{title:"name4",count:3},{title:"name5",count:8}];

//for each A, loop through B's. If a match is found combine the Counts in A.
for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<B.length;j++){
    if(A[i].title == B[j].title){
        A[i].count += B[j].count;
    }
  }
}

//find all B's that were not combined with A in the previous step, and push them into A.
for(var i=0;i<B.length;i++){
    noMatch = true;
    for(var j=0;j<A.length;j++){
    if(B[i].title == A[j].title){
        B[i].count += A[j].count;
      noMatch = false;
    }
  }
  if(noMatch){A.push(B[i]);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a simple 3 line answer (minus the A/B vars); utilizes the fact that objects must have unique keys

```
var A = [{title:"name1",count:5},{title:"name2",count:1},{title:"name3",count:3}];
var B = [{title:"name2",count:7},{title:"name3",count:2},{title:"name4",count:3},{title:"name5",count:8}];

var o = {};
A.concat(B).forEach(function(a){o[a.title] = o.hasOwnProperty(a.title)? o[a.title]+a.count: a.count});
var AB = Object.keys(o).map(function(j){ return {title:j,count:o[j]} });
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal is merging and counting with a temporary object and [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var arrayA = [{ title: "name1", count: 5 }, { title: "name2", count: 1 }, { title: "name3", count: 3 }],
    arrayB = [{ title: "name2", count: 7 }, { title: "name3", count: 2 }, { title: "name4", count: 3 }, { title: "name5", count: 8 }],
    result = function (array) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.title in o)) {
                o[a.title] = { title: a.title, count: 0 };
                r.push(o[a.title]);
            }
            o[a.title].count += a.count;
        });
        return r;
    }(arrayA.concat(arrayB));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#concat) `._concat` function :

```
var result = _.concat(A, B);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7ywwm33/)